# Return the value of the tuple choices in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to return the string representation of the object, but it returns the code instead. How can i get the second item of the tuple?

[image]

```
PACKAGE_TYPES = [
    ('FR','Free'),
    ('BA','Basic'),
    ('PR','Professional'),
]

class Package(models.Model):
    package_type = models.CharField(choices=PACKAGE_TYPES,max_length=2,default='FR')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.package_type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_package_type_display()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display